# matplotlib: ugly plots when using markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a little problem. I have a program that will draw wave function for a potential, and it looks fine when I use the option in plot (using pylab) '-' for instance: http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/8798/59138635.png

If I use 'o' i'll get:
http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3741/22378006.png

You see that it looks ugly :\

Is there a simple way to make the circles more spaced, or does that depends on the details of the code?

The code is:

```
from math import *
from scipy.special import *
from pylab import *
from scipy.linalg import *

firebrick=(178./255.,34./255.,34./255.)
indianred=(176./255.,23./255.,31./255.)
steelblue=(70./255.,130./255.,180./255.)
slategray1=(198./255.,226./255.,255./255.)
slategray4=(108./255.,123./255.,139./255.)
lavender=(230./255.,230./255.,230./255.)
cobalt=(61./255.,89./255.,171./255.)
midnightblue=(25./255.,25./255.,112./255.)
forestgreen=(34./255.,139./255.,34./255.)

#grid
Nmesh=512
L=4.0
dx=L/Nmesh
Xmax=L
x=arange(-L,L+0.0001,dx)
Npts=len(x)
numwav=2   #number of wave function that is being drawn

V=zeros([Npts],float)
for i in range(Npts):
    V[i]=x[i]**4

a=zeros([2,Npts-2],float)
wave=zeros([Npts],float)

wave1=zeros([Npts],float)
encor=3.0/4*(3.0/4)**(1.0/3)

#numerical solution
for i in range(1,Npts-1,1):
    a[0,i-1]= 1.0/dx**2+V[i]     #diagonal elements
    a[1,i-1]=-1.0/dx**2/2        #the elements below the diagonal
a[1,Npts-3]=-99.0                #element is not used
eig,vec=eig_banded(a,lower=1)    #routine that diagonalizes the tridiagonal matrix

for i in range(1,Npts-1,1):
    wave[i]=vec[i-1,numwav]
wave[0]=0.0             #wave function has the value zero on the first point on the grid
wave[Npts-1]=0.0        #wave function has the value zero on the last point on the grid

wave=150*wave+eig[numwav]

#potential graph
line=plt.plot(x,V)
plt.setp(line,color='firebrick',linewidth=2)

#plot of the selected level and wave function
plt.axhline(y=eig[numwav],linewidth=2,color='steelblue')

#plot of the points of the wave function
plt.plot(x,wave,"b-",linewidth=2,color='forestgreen')

plt.xlabel('x',size=16)
plt.ylabel('V(x)',size=16)
plt.axis([-4.0,4.0,-5.0,16.0]) #x and y axes range
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I answered your question, but there are some serious improvements to your code that you can make. For example, instead of using `range`, use numpy's built-in vector operations: `V = x**4` can replace all three of those lines.

Comment: If you have spatially unevenly distributed markers, then you would want an acrlength parameterization for markers, which is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406758/plotting-a-curve-with-equidistant-arc-length-markers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After investigating further, I have a better (but different) answer. Matplotlib provides a `markevery` keyword to allow a stride in placing markers. So I would recommend, if you want 20 or so points for visibility, on top of a green line:

```
stride = max( int(len(x) / 20), 1)
plt.plot(x,wave,"-o",color='forestgreen', markevery=stride)
```

My previous answer works fine if you only want markers, but this works much better if you want both lines and markers.

Comment: I will add it and see what I get :) Thanks for the help ^^

Answer (score 2):

The reason it looks ugly is that your grid is too finely spaced for plotting with markers. What you can do to add markers to your line is to only add them to every 10 (or whatever) points:

```
plt.plot(x[::10],wave[::10],"o",color='forestgreen')
```

Comment: +1... @dingo_d: remember that when you plot data using matplotlib, you're not giving it a function, you're giving it a discrete list of points. It will draw a marker at each one of those individual points. So if you want to see fewer circles, simply give matplotlib a more sparse list of points.